# How do I get PHP strip_tags to remove HTML and Script tags but not XML?

Tags: php, html, xml, strip-tags

I was using the php strip_tags() function to remove html tags from my text area input and to remove < script > tags to help guard against scripting attacks.

Anyway, often times the user is going to need to input XML tags that are not known in advance. However, my strip_tags function is removing these benign xml tags as well, which is not acceptable.

Also, I'll sometimes put filename.< date>.png (had to add a space there because StackOverflow removed it as well lol) to indicate variable parts of a file name or path. In this case what I end up with is filename..png after strip_tags is run.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: since xml also uses tags, you cannot. besides, it would basically defeat the purpose of string tags, since you can still cram javascript into any unknown tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strip_tags()` is defined as removing all HTML/XML tags (other than the individual tags specified in the second argument). There is no distinction between the two types of tags, nor between that and `<date>` used as a placeholder -- all three look like tags to `strip_tags()`, so it removes them.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to make `strip_tags` not remove unknown tags. You may want to look at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$s = preg_replace("/<\?xml(.*?)\?>/i", "<xmlDeclaration$1>", $s);
$s = strip_tags($s, '<xmlDeclaration><' . implode('><', $allowedTags) . '>');
$s = preg_replace("/<xmlDeclaration(.*?)>/i", "<?xml$1?>", $s);
```